# unable to catch 404 error (resource not found) in Ember JS setupController hook while assigning model to the template

Tags: rest, ember.js, error-handling, http-status-code-404, ember-data

I have a route `/users/:user_id` in emberjs application and I am assigning a model to the template in setupController hook of a App.UserRoute class as:

```
controller.store.find('user', model.id).then(onSuccess, onError);

var onSuccess = function(user) {

if(user) {
    // reload Model to forcefully fetch from server
    user.reload().then(function() { /* some processing */ }, function(error_response) { /* some error handling */ });

    // assign model for user
        controller.set('model', user);
    }
};

var onError = function(reason) { /* some error handling */ };
```

Now this gives me an error 404 from server when I am looking for an user-id which does not exists. I am trying to catch this error and display appropriate message and redirect to the list of all users (`/users`). But I am unable to catch it and I get an error from ember : `Error while loading route: undefined`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real thing is you are passing in `undefined` to your `then` method.  You should move your declaration of your callback functions to before the promise code.

```
var onSuccess = function(user) {

  if(user) {
    // reload Model to forcefully fetch from server
    user.reload().then(function() { /* some processing */ }, function(error_response) { /* some error handling */ });

    // assign model for user
        controller.set('model', user);
    }
  };

var onError = function(reason) { /* some error handling */ };

controller.store.find('user', model.id).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some implementation details that I think could be improved:

1) You do not need to set your model in the controller. Ember assigns it to the value resolved by the promise in the route **model hook**.

```
model: function(params) {

  var user = this.store.getById('user', params.id);

  if (user) {
    return user.reload();
  } else {
    return this.store.find('user', params.id);
  }

}
```

2) You could catch your promise error in the error event handler of your route.

```
    actions: {
      error: function(error) {
         // print error
        this.transitionTo('users');
      }
    }
```

You could take a look at the [Ember Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) to check how Error and Loading substates are managed by the router.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you yourself are catching the failure and processing it via the second argument to `then`. This turns failure into success. You will need to rethrow the error so it is picked up by the `error` hook you have defined. One way would be

```
user.reload().then(
    function() { /* some processing */ }, 
    function(error_response) { /* some error handling */ }.catch(RSVP.rethrow)
});
```

It would also most likely work to do

```
user.reload().then(function() { /* some processing */ }, 
    function(error_response) { 
        /* some error handling */
        throw "reload failed";
    }
);
```

More generally, consider the following code:

```
rejected_promise.then(
    success1 /* won't be called */
    function rejected() { return 0; }
)
.then(
    success2 /* will be called */
    rejected2 /* won't be called */
);
```

Here, `rejected2` won't be called; rather, `success2` will be. That is because a rejection handler is considered to **fulfill** the promise (make it succeed), unless it rethrows.